# Certain capital letters do not "work"

Tags: keyboard, characters, shift

ɪ have a strange issue. Certain capital letters do not work and produce letters which look like them but are small and do not "count" as letters in word processors.

Exampleː n - ɴ, h - ʜ, i - ɪ, r - ʀ, y-ʏ, g - ɢ, l - ʟ.

When using caps-lock they come out as lowercase. When using shift they display as above. This is accross all programs. ɪt's more of a quality of life thing, but it is rather frustrating.

Comment: What keyboard driver are you using and what font?

Comment: Oh, and operating system as well. Without all this info your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I'm guessing he's from Turkey.